# Cant invoke jquery function from asp.net code behind

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Im new to javascript/Jquery

I have made a javascript/Jquery applet witch i will use to display feedback from my asp.net application to the end user. Like a fancy pop up that slides in and have different functionality depending if the message is of status "error" "alert" or "success".

(I know this has been done before and there are plug ins and stuff to do it. Im not posting this cause i need the solution solved, im posting because i need to understand what i am doing wrong and learn how to properly invoke my js/jq functions.)

The asp.net codebehind method that invokes the jq function uses the RegisterClientScriptBlock(); The method works if i just put alert("whatever"); instead of invoking the pop up function. If i make a dummy js function outside of the document ready it also works. But when i try and invoke my pop up alert function nothing happens. It doesnt even go inside the function.

C#

```
public void SendPopUp()
{
string key = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
StringBuilder javascript = new StringBuilder();

javascript.Append("$(document).ready(function() {");
javascript.Append(" AlertPopUp('Horror', 'Oh nooo, an error is simulated!', 'error');");

 javascript.Append(" });");

// Gets the executing web page 
Page page = HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler as Page;


ScriptManager sm = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(page);


if (sm != null && sm.IsInAsyncPostBack)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(page, typeof(Page), key,javascript.ToString() , true);
}
else
{
    page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), key,javascript.ToString() , true);
}


}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
<script type="text/javascript">


    /*
    ------------USER FEEDBACK POPUP-------------
    ---------Lautaro Arino @Viatel 2011---------
    --------------------------------------------
    */




    $(function () {

        // ID of DIVS
        var popUpId = "AlertPopUp";
        var popUpCollapseId = "AlertCollapse";
        var popUpDisbandId = "AlertDisband";
        var titleId = "AlertTitle";
        var messageId = "AlertMessage";
        var bodyId = "AlertBody";
        var headerId = "AlertHeader";
        var imageId = "AlertImage";

        // Get the div objects
        var PopUpBox = $('#' + popUpId);
        var CollapseDiv = $('#' + popUpCollapseId);
        var DisbandDiv = $('#' + popUpDisbandId);
        var TitleDiv = $("#" + titleId);
        var MessageDiv = $("#" + messageId);
        var Image = $('#' + imageId);

        //Paths to error images
        var successImagePath = "images/okej.jpg";
        var alertImagePath = "images/alert.jpg";
        var errorImagePath = "images/error.jpg";
        var rootPathFromThisFile = "../../";

        //parameters
        var anmationSpeed = 300; //milliseconds. speed of the popup showing up, expanding and collapsing
        var fadOutSpeed = 5000; //milliseconds. speed of success messages fading out
        var popupWidth = PopUpBox.width();
        var collapseWidth = DisbandDiv.width() + Image.width();



        //EVENT HANDLERS 
        DisbandDiv.click(function () {
            disbandPoPUp();
        });


        PopUpBox.click(function () {

            if (state == "expanded") {
                collapse();

            } else if (state == "collapsed") {
                expand();
            }
        });

        //testbutton
        $('#btnerror').click(function () {

            AlertPopUp('Jättehemskt!', 'Oh nooo, an error is simulated!', 'error');
        });

        $('#btnalert').click(function () {
            AlertPopUp('Glöm ej. ', 'Glöm ej att köpa mjölk', 'alert');
        });

        $('#btnsuccess').click(function () {
            AlertPopUp('Woho!', 'Någonting har gått som det ska!', 'success');
        });




        //DISBAND
        function disbandPoPUp() {
            // alert("disbanding");
            PopUpBox.stop();
            PopUpBox.css('display', 'none');
            state = "off";
        };

        //COLLAPSE
        function collapse() {
            //  alert("collapsing");
            PopUpBox.animate({ "right": -popupWidth + collapseWidth + 10 + "px" }, 300);
            state = "collapsed";
        };

        //EXPAND 
        function expand() {
            //   alert("expanding");
            PopUpBox.animate({ "right": "-5px" }, 300);
            state = "expanded";
        };





        //AlertPopUp('Jättehemskt!', 'Oh nooo, an error is simulated!', 'error');

        function AlertPopUp(title, message, type) {
          //  alert("function invoked");

            //RESET POSITION
            PopUpBox.css('right', -popupWidth + "px");
            PopUpBox.css('opacity', '1.0');
            PopUpBox.stop(); // in case there is an animation or fade going on

            //SET MESSAGE

            TitleDiv.text(title);
            MessageDiv.text(message);



            // SET POP UP TYPE AND DISPLAY
            if (type == "success") {
                // SUCESS
                setBorderAndImage("green", successImagePath);
                setFadeOut();

            } else if (type == "alert") {
                //ALERT
                setBorderAndImage("orange", alertImagePath);
                displayPopUpExpanded();

            } else {
                //ERROR

                setBorderAndImage("red", errorImagePath);
                displayPopUpExpanded();
            }


            //DISPLAY EXPANDED
            function displayPopUpExpanded() {
                PopUpBox.css('display', 'block');
                expand();
            }



            //DISPLAY COLLAPSED
            function displayPopUpCollapsed() {
                PopUpBox.css('display', 'block');
                collapse();
            }


            function setFadeOut() {
                PopUpBox.css('display', 'block');
                PopUpBox.animate({ "right": "-5px" }, anmationSpeed,
                         function () {
                             state = "expanded";
                             startFadeKill();
                         }
                         );


                function startFadeKill() {
                    PopUpBox.fadeTo(fadOutSpeed, 1.0, function () {//this is just a delay before starting to fade out.
                        PopUpBox.fadeTo(fadOutSpeed, 0.0, function () {
                            //  alert("fade done");
                            disbandPoPUp();
                        });
                    });


                    PopUpBox.mouseenter(function () {
                        //alert("mouse");
                        PopUpBox.stop();
                        PopUpBox.fadeTo("fast", 1.0);
                    });
                }
            }


            //Set border color and image
            function setBorderAndImage(color, imagePath) {
                PopUpBox.css("border-color", color);
                DisbandDiv.css("background-color", color);

                //set image path
                Image.attr("src", rootPathFromThisFile + imagePath);
                }
        };



    })



</script>
```

Comment: Do you get javascript errors?

Comment: I've recreated your setup and I cant reproduce the error. The javascript function executes fine. I also cant seem to find your `AlertPopUp` function definition in the code you've posted.

Comment: Im sorry you all. I did not manage to post all the code. I have edited the post and it includes everything now f0x.

Comment: Tim B james. No i dont get any js errors. The PopUpalert) function is just not invoked.

Comment: @Lautaro - there are quite a few formatting issues but before that, could you try to use `RegisterStartupScript` instead of `RegisterClientScriptBlock` and try again.

Comment: f0x. Thanks for your time. I tried this just now. I dont understand it. `RegisterStartupScript` asks for a control as the first parameter. But since this is a csharp class and not a page there are no controls. Also the registerClientScriptBlock works for other js calls like alert();. How should i proceed?

Comment: @Lautaro - does the `AlertPopUp` function work when you call it from another piece of code? it seems like the end brace `}` is misplaced at a glance. Also, `RegisterStartupScript` is the correct use for executing code at a page startup. the usage is as follows `RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), key,javascript.ToString(), true);` Off a quick hand.

Comment: @fOx The AlertPopUp works perfectly when for example invoked by clicking a button that i have set up as a test.
So i am correct then to use RegisterStartUpScript as i have done?

Comment: @f0x Also, if you still see formatting issues i would be grateful if you would point them out to me.

Comment: @Lautaro - the reason i would like you to try `RegisterStartUpScript` instead of `ScriptBlock` is because `ScriptBlock` is registered right above your content and before your custom script is loaded. ie. `alert` would work since you dont need any DOM elements to be loaded - pure JS. `RegisterStartupScript` is placed after all the element on your page and thus, In my opinion would solve your issue.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4061/discussion-between-f0x-and-lautaro)

Answer (score 2):

It's because both your calling function and the the actual function you're calling are bound to the document load events.

The `RegisterClientScriptBlock` script is placed before the javascript handler, and since JQuery calls each handler in turn; when it registers the backend generated script, the `AlertPopup` function has not yet been registered. So remove the javascript functions other than the event handlers and place them outside `$(function(){});`

Comment: Got it! So the script i register is in the RegisterStartupScript and contains `$(function(){})` 
In the js file, the `AlertPopUp` declaration is outside of `$(function(){})` but the initiation is inside. But can i make the pop up display with this method even if its called from a partial update, for example during a grid view updating inside a update panel causing an error.

Thanks anyhow!

Comment: Yes, AlertPopup declaration should be made prior to the document load, and the call to it can remain as it is. You could even globally extend your jQuery object with your alert functions if you'd like, through a script in a master page for instance. `ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock` should work for postbacks and AJAX requests as well.